# How do I rank my web application's posts?

Tags: algorithm, formula, data-science, ranking

I'm setting up a web application, and want to rank posts so that every post gets activity during some point of time. (i.e they get displayed on the 1st page or amongst the top posts despite their views or activity).

I already have an idea about how the Reddit post ranking method works, and I guess stack overflow uses similar kind of algorithms to rank their posts.

Something I have noticed a lot is that some posts when they are new and there isn't much activity during the first few hours it gets way below the list of posts (replaced by newer posts). Of course, this is reasonable.

The basic scenario of my application is users post tasks they want to get done, then people interested will apply. The user who posted will shortlist candidates and then finally hire. Here, once the user gets to the shortlisting process, it's no longer useful to be ranked at the top. I want them to be replaced by other tasks posted(which haven't received applications) + new posts.

Are there any algorithms present, that works around this model?
My question may not be straightforward, if so please feel free to ask questions regarding this.
Thank You

Comment: You can use a time based sorting that is put the more recent posts on top.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. Your solution causes the relatively older posts with minimum activity or applications to be replaced by the newer posts. As I mentioned, that's not what I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to find the attributes that you care about, for example: `Recency`, `Popularity` and define a score as a linear function of these attributes where you will need to determine the `weights` `w` that make sense:

```
score = wR * Recency + wP * Popularity
```

On the other side of the spectrum, if you want to go complex, there is a [variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) of ranking algorithms.

Comment: I found the Round Robin Scheduling algorithm (used for resource allocation for CPU functions) best fitting for my application. I am going to use an extension of this algorithm.